# Setting COM (RDPEncomAPI) property in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com, rdp

I've used Delphi for some time, but I am trying some COM programming and having trouble. I apologize if this is a NewBie issue, but after searching an trying lots of things I have not been able to get or set the properties of an RDPEncom RDPSession object. The code (including several naive attemps) is below. If I remove the line attempting to read properties, remaining code works fine.

**How can I get and Set the PortID property of RDPSession.Properties ?**

```
uses rdpencomapi_TLB;  // from JWAPI

...

myRDPSession := CoRDPSession.Create();
if VarIsNull(myRDPSession) then
begin
  application.MessageBox('MsRdpSession creation failed.', 'Error');
  Result := False;
  Exit;
end;
try
  didShare := myRDPSession.Open;
except
  ShowMessage('Unable to share desktop !');
  Exit;
end;
theProperty := 'PortID';
ActiveXProp := myRDPSession.Properties;
//lValues := ActiveXProp.Property_(theProperty); // method not supported
//lValues := ActiveXProp.Property(theProperty); // member not found
myRDPSession.Properties.GetProperty(lValues, myRDPSession.Properties.Property, theProperty);
{
 ALL RETURN INVALID NUMBER OF PARAMETERS..
    ActiveXProp.GetProperty(lValues, ActiveXProp.Property, 'PortID');
    ActiveXProp.Property.GetProperty(ActiveXProp.Property, lValues, 'PortID');
    ActiveXProp.Property.GetProperty(lValues, ActiveXProp, 'PortID');
    ActiveXProp.Property.Get_Prop_('PortID', ActiveXProp);
    ActiveXProp.Property.SetProperty('PortID', ActiveXProp);
    ActiveXProp.Property.Set_Prop_('PortID', ActiveXProp);
}
ActiveXInvite := myRDPSession.Invitations.CreateInvitation('RemoteSupport', 'WePresent', '12345', 75);

...
```

Comment: What is the definition of `RDPSession.Properties`? (How is it declared in the source for IRDPSession?) I'd suspect it's either `Variant` (which probably means a Variant array) or a collection of some sort; either way, it's plural, which means that there is more than one entry, which means some sort of iteration through the contents.

Comment: Ken:  RDPSession.Properties  in the TLB unit it is a IDispatch interface with no actual properties defined, but with Get_Property_ and Set_Property_ functions. According to MSDN Get and Set are the only ways to get at the properties..  Unfortunately I haven't been able to get or set them that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ken,

Your comment put me onto something.. I regenerated the TLB file from my own machine and found it did have a property that was not in the TLB I used originally (from Jedi Project). This one has a single Property called 'Property' that allowed me to do what I needed. Basically I was missing the COM interface point. I got it to work after updating the TLB this way (with no error checking yet):

```
// get properties interface
myRDPSessionProp := myRDPSession.Properties;
// set listening port
myRDPSessionProp.Property['PortID'] := 59000;
// set color depth
myRDPSession.colorDepth := 8;
didShare := myRDPSession.Open;
```